# A multiple web-app backup script

Tags: backup, scripting, web-applications, cms

I'm mostly a Drupal developer, and have a backup script that goes through each site and uses [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to perform a db dump, before archiving all the sites and their dumps. I've just finished a small Wordpress project, and so now my script can't automatically back that site up. I was wondering if anybody knew of any pre-existing scripts that could handle backing up a variety of typical open-source web CMSs? Ideally it would discover the db name (and prefix if necessary) and dump it; allow me to specify some areas not to back up (eg. large images directory); and work with rsync, although that's for future use.

Any suggestions, or advice to tell me I'm thinking about it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am actually going to tell you that you should do this differently. From my perspective the purpose of backups is to get back to a working scenario as quickly as possible. That is only possible if your backups cover all databases and all code on your server. Depending on your choice of recovery speed this may include the OS itself (unbeaten for bare metal recovery).

So my suggestion would be to install bacula and configure it to cover all your websites and all databases, plus everything in etc or wherever you have customized configuration files. That way you can retrieve individual files if needed, or you can just recover everything in one swell foop.